# Why am i getting a list index out of range error in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

The error occurs in line  `if data[l][0] == value:`

```
def binary_pairs(data, value):
    l = 0
    h = len(data) - 1
    while l < h and data[l]!= value:
        m = (h + l) // 2
        if data[m][0] == value:
            l = m
        elif data[m][0] < value:
            l = m + 1
        else:
            h = m - 1
    print("done")
    if data[l][0] == value:
        return l
    else:
        return -1
```

example input: 
    [ [ "dead", ["brian.txt","grail.txt"] ],
    [ "eunt", ["brian.txt"] ],
    [ "spank", ["grail.txt"] ]
    ]

Comment: Could you add some example input?

Comment: Print out "data" after "def" (before l=0) to see what do you get in binary_pairs function.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two potential issues with your code:

- It seems odd that you use both `data[l]` and `data[l][0]` in comparisons.
- If, for example, `l==0` and `h==1` and you end up taking the `else` (`h = m - 1`), you'd end up with `h==-1`, which is out of bounds. There could be other similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code right now but here are a few ideas.

- If you are trying to solve a problem, rather than trying to learn to write a binary search, consider using Python's `bisect` module.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

- It is best practice in Python to comply with the coding standard called PEP 8; this recommends not using lower-case L as a variable name, or upper-case I.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

- It would be cleaner to have the loop immediately return the index when it finds the value, rather than having the loop test at the top to make sure the value hasn't been found yet, causing the loop to end and then the value to be returned from the bottom of the function.  If the loop ends, you can return `-1` at the end of the function.
- Your loop checks that the index is `< h` but does not check that the index is I `>= 0`.  I suspect that this could be your problem.
- When debugging a loop like this, it is often helpful to add print statements that log what is going on.  You should print the value of the index, and print enough other lines to know whether it is being increased or decreased, and by how much.